# Error in rval[i, j, drop = drop., ...] : Subscript out of bounds - using the eventstudies package in R

Tags: r, quantitative-finance

I'm trying to run an event study for multiple firms and multiple events. Input is essentially a simple data frame containing tickers in one column and event dates in the other. This is extracted from WRDS and then loaded into R. The rest of the code should be running directly. To try my code, you could use data(SplitDates) from the package instead of Annoucements.

```
library(eventstudies)
library(estudy2)
library(tidyquant)
library(quantmod)

#load announcement dates
Announcements = read.csv2(file ="Dates_short_test.csv", sep=";", header=FALSE)
str(Announcements)
colnames(Announcements) = c("name", "when")
Announcements$when = as.Date(Announcements$when)

#get stock prices
tickers = c("IBM", "MSFT")

getSymbols(tickers,
           from = "2009-01-01",
           to = "2016-01-15")

ClosePrices <- do.call(merge, lapply(tickers, function(x) Cl(get(x))))

#get S&P500
SPX <- getSymbols("^GSPC",auto.assign = FALSE, from = "2009-01-01",
                  to = "2016-01-15")

#Only keep closing price
SPX1 = SPX[,4]

#Returns SPX
SPX_Ret = (exp(diff(log(SPX1))) - 1) *100
SPX_Ret1 = SPX_Ret[-1]

#Returns Stocks
Stock_Returns = (exp(diff(log(ClosePrices))) - 1) *100
Stock_Returns1 = Stock_Returns[-1]

#create zoo variables as required in the manual of the package

Stock_Returns2 = as.zoo(Stock_Returns1)
SPX_Ret2 = as.zoo(SPX1)


#conduct event study
Event_study_results<- eventstudy(firm.returns = Stock_Returns2,
event.list = Announcements,
event.window = 5,
type = "marketModel",
to.remap = TRUE,
remap = "cumsum",
inference = TRUE,
inference.strategy = "bootstrap",
model.args = list(market.returns=SPX_Ret2))
```

What it returns is

```
Error in rval[i, j, drop = drop., ...] : 
 Subscript out of bounce
```

I know it's probably a stupid mistake but I can't find it myself.

Thanks!